# UWP turn off kiosk mode

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, kiosk

I have an UWP application published to the Windows Store and this app can be start into kiosk mode (assigned access).
It's works great, but I try to create an button on the app to turn off the kiosk mode and to return to the windows loggin screen. I tried the code given in the doc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/mt633799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

```
LockApplicationHost lockHost = LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView();
if (lockHost != null)
{
    lockHost.RequestUnlock();
}
```

But I clicked to the button, the app just close and reopen. But don't exit the kiosk mode... I have an excpetion throw in the store, but it's empty.
[image: store exception]

Can someone help me to understand the problem ?

**EDIT**

This is the exception :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
    at Windows.ApplicationModel.LockScreen.LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView()
    at Kiwi.Views.Shell.CloseButton_Tapped(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in my side. I think you can try with a new blank project with only one button to test it again. As the doc said: ***"If the kiosk app ends unexpectedly, the assigned access framework tries to relaunch it. "***, you can try with [Unlocking event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.lockscreen.lockapplicationhost.unlocking) and exit the app like in the example.

Comment: I have try with a blank project and the issue is the same. But the problem appears only at x64 plateform, but not for x86 ! I think it's maybe a communication problem with Int32 and Int64 when the app try to send a signal to windows...

Comment: That's weird. I also tested with x64 plateform and it works well. Have you tested with any other device? Do they have the same problem? Besides, the settings [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/manage/set-up-a-kiosk-for-windows-10-for-desktop-editions) might also helpful.

Comment: I have try on 5 differents devices (4 in x64 and one in x86) and it's only works on x86. Do you compile for specific plateform ? I call method in the "Tapped" event for button, that's right ?

Comment: I have found the solution, I will post the answer. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, I simply add this two Extension in the manifest :

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.lockScreenCall" />
<uap:Extension Category="windows.aboveLockScreen" />
```

And now it's works great!