# How to Exit UWP Kiosk app under lock screen

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, kiosk, kiosk-mode

We have a UWP app which we use it as kiosk application.

For exiting from the kiosk app, the below method works without any issues when app is `aboveLockScreen`

```
LockApplicationHost lockHost = LockApplicationHost.GetForCurrentView();
if (lockHost != null)
{
    lockHost.RequestUnlock();
}
```

For this the following extensions are added in manifest file,

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.lockScreenCall" />
<uap:Extension Category="windows.aboveLockScreen" />
```

Now in our case,
We will be unable to use this extension
`<uap:Extension Category="windows.aboveLockScreen" />` since we will be creating new views which will cause exceptions. Please refer MS Docs on this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/partnerapps/create-a-kiosk-app-for-assigned-access#multiple-views-windows-and-threads-

[image]

I hope When those extensions are removed the app will be under Lock Screen as per the docs.
[image]

Now my problem is i tried exiting with the existing code and my app crashes.
Can Someone please help how to exit from kiosk app under Lock view?

The [UWP turn off kiosk mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41220975/uwp-turn-off-kiosk-mode)  question explains above lock view, it would be useful if someone say how to exit from under lock view

We tried to trigger Ctrl+Alt+Delete from code and tried signing out, but couldn't do it from code. Any help or suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Have you tried calling Application.Current.Exit() ?

Comment: Yes, I did. exiting or crashing will restart the app in kiosk mode.

Comment: Hi, A single app running on Kiosk will not be closed with lockview (if you are not unlock it). As you tried, the app will automatically restart when you exit the app.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Single kiosk app with windows.aboveLockScreen extension can go to login screen which will be used to exit from kiosk mode, my concern is without that extension how could we exit from kiosk mode. The reason for removing that extension is described on the question.

Comment: I noticed that the app crashed when you tried to quit the app. Maybe this will be the reason. Can you provide detailed information about the crash (such as related code) and event log? This helps us solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryConsolidateAsync()`??

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Acr.UserDialogs?
It works when I replace Acr.UserDialogs with a different way to show dialogs.

Comment: Please [edit] to reduce the impression of "I have the same problem and no idea how to solve it." Because I think that there is an actual answer hidden in here, even if an unexplained one....